# Zend - How to enable cache(MetaData) on session table?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, cache-control

i am using Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable to store the session in a table

my profiler tells me that on each page request zend does:

#  Query   Time

(1)     connect     0.0032038688659668

(2)     DESCRIBE `session`  0.0041539669036865

(3)     SELECT `session`.* FROM `session` WHERE (((`session`.`session_id` = '7nnan8ltd6h64sigs6dlkicvh0' AND `session`.`save_path` = '' AND `session`.`name` = 'PHPSESSID')))   0.00057697296142578

Total time : 0.008 sec

when i do queries on other tables, zend DESCRIBEs them once(the first time it access that table), then if i refresh the page it only does the query with no Describe, on the session table it does DESCRIBE on every page (since i use authentication ... )

how can i cache **only the metadata** on the session table?

i am currently using this

```
class Gestionale_Application_Resource_Cache extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract{
public function init ()
{
    $options = $this->getOptions();

    // Get a Zend_Cache_Core object

    //valori che vengono presi dal file di configurazione
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
        $options['frontEnd'],
        $options['backEnd'],
        $options['frontEndOptions'],
        $options['backEndOptions']);
    Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);

    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);//per mettere in cache la meta-info
    return $cache;
}
```

this is my config file

```
...
;cache stuff
resources.cache.frontEnd = core 
resources.cache.backEnd = file 
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.lifetime = 1200 ; in secondi
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.automatic_serialization = true 
resources.cache.backEndOptions.lifetime = 3600 ; in secondi
resources.cache.backEndOptions.cache_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../cache"
pluginPaths.Gestionale_Application_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Gestionale/Application/Resource"  
;;fine cache stuff

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "gestionale"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Gestionale_";serve per caricare il plugin di sotto quando si usa anche ZFdebug
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Gestionale_Controller_Plugin_Acl"
resources.db.params.profiler = true
...
```

this is my session table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session` (
  `session_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `save_path` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `modified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lifetime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`,`save_path`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

thanks :D

Comment: Where are you defining the session save handler? If you're doing it in the config file, make sure the cache definition comes first. Otherwise there is no default metadata cache available when the Zend_Db_Table object for the session gets created.

Comment: @squirrel you were right, all i had to do was add one line 
 protected function _initSession()
 {

   $this->bootstrap('cache');, if you would post your answer i will assign it as the right answer in order to give you the bounty :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you are initializing the session save handler, either in the bootstrap or the config file, make sure that you call Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache() first.

To specify it in your config file, put the session config after the `;;fine cache stuff` line:

```
...
;cache stuff
resources.cache.frontEnd = core 
resources.cache.backEnd = file 
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.lifetime = 1200 ; in secondi
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.automatic_serialization = true 
resources.cache.backEndOptions.lifetime = 3600 ; in secondi
resources.cache.backEndOptions.cache_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../cache"
pluginPaths.Gestionale_Application_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Gestionale/Application/Resource"  
;;fine cache stuff

resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "session"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary[] = "session_id"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary[] = "save_path"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary[] = "name"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment[] = "sessionId"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment[] = "sessionSavePath"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment[] = "sessionName"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "modified"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "session_data"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
...
```

Or, if you don't want to rely on their order in the config file, you can add an `_initSession()` method to your bootstrap class that specifically loads them in the correct order:

```
protected function _initSession()
{
    $this->bootstrap('cache');
    $this->bootstrap('session');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify cache named as 'dbMetadataCache' and it will cache metadata of all tables.

Here is a example using APC as a backend

```
resources.cachemanager.dbMetadataCache.frontend.name = "Core"
resources.cachemanager.dbMetadataCache.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = 1
resources.cachemanager.dbMetadataCache.frontend.options.caching = 1
resources.cachemanager.dbMetadataCache.backend.name = "Apc"

resources.db.defaultMetadataCache = "dbMetadataCache"
```

Comment: it breaks this if i change the config file $cache = $bootstrap->getResource('cache'); $container = $cache->load($cacheKey);

Comment: With the cache manager you can specify multiple cache instances. Each of them can use different backend's and so on. You can then fetch the spesified cache byt name like this. 
    $manager = $bootstrap->getResource('cachemanager');
    $manager->getCache($cacheName)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add the 'resources.db.defaultMetadataCache' entry.

Comment: i really appreaciate your help, but i had to change 4 files and i still get errors... Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'No entry is registered for key 'cache''  i prefer squirrel's solution where i add one line and everything works :D

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know what else you are doing with the cache in the registry. If you add the lines above and remove the line Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache); from your resource class it should work. Remember to edit the dbMetadataCache properties to the right ones.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me.  Seamlessly.  I switched to using Libmemcached as the backend, but basically a copy and paste solution.